# Creating a dataframe with Predicted Output and input test data in python

Tags: python, dataframe, machine-learning, prediction

I built an ML model and it works fine but now I am looking for a way where I can know which input test data used gave me the predicted result so that I can create it as a dictionary.

I am trying this because in my model some inputs will be skipped by the model so the ordering gets mixed up.

Expected output is below

enter image description here

Could someone please help me in creating this data

Below is the dataframe constructor of input data used for training

```
import pandas as pd
Names = ['Apple','Orange','Apple', 'Orange', 'Orange', 'Car', 'Truck', 
         'Cycle', 'VolleyBall', 'BasketBall', 'VolleyBall', 'Car', 'Truck','Cycle', 
        'BasketBall'] 
Labels = ['Fruit','Fruit', 'Fruit', 'Fruit', 'Fruit', 'Automobile','Automobile', 'Automobile',
        'Sports', 'Sport', 'Sports', 'Automobile', 'Automobile','Automobile'
        , 'Sports']

df = pd.DataFrame(Labels, Names).reset_index()
df.columns = ['Names', 'Labels']
df
```

The test Data I am using for prediction is **['Unknown', 'Orange', 'Car', 'BasketBall']**

Now my model will skip the input test data 'Unknown' and only predict values for the remaining three in the form **['Fruit', 'Automobile', 'Sports']**

I am trying to achieve the result in the form of a dataframe with the input test data and predicted output.

Answer (score 0):

I am writing this as an answer because I don't have enough rep to comment!

A possible reason your model is skipping unknown categories is you might not have mentioned `handle_unknown = 'ignore'` when OneHotEncoding your features. Try it and lemme know if it solves your problem.

As to how you can get the results of the predicted data, simply create a dataframe of the data you want the predictions on and use `model.predict` on that dataframe. You will get a dataframe with the resuts.